# Excel input and output in same cell

Tags: excel, formula

I'm not a programmer and I need some help!

I have an excel sheet where I want to have a formula in the background and when I input a number I want it to be calculated in the formula without deleting it in the same cell.

The formula is like this **X*6.75%+X** , where **X** is the input.
Some help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You cannot do that. Period!! Your sole option is to have two cells, one for input and one for output, being the last (output) the one hosting the formula.

Comment: The only way to achieve what you want would be modifying the formula every time you want to calculate something. In example, if you type in a cell `=(2*0.0675)+2` you will get in the same cell `2.135`. If you change manually the `2` and type `10` then you'll get `10.675`. But this is the worst way of working in Excel. It would be easier indeed in 2 cells, and just change the number in a cell. But if you need it, whatever the reason it is, I'm afraid the only way to do this is the way I told.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't tagged as requiring VBA, but that's the only way I can think of achieving this.
As @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns says - you'd have to update the formula each time without VBA.

For a VBA method you'd add this code to the specific worksheet module (updating the cell reference as required):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then
        If IsNumeric(Target) Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            'Target = Target * 6.75 / 100 + Target 'Place value in cell.
            Target.Formula = "=" & Target & "* 6.75 / 100 + " & Target 'Update formula in cell.
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

**Edit:** I've updated code to include suggestions in comments.

Comment: Hi @DarrenBartrup-Cook , I had almost the exact same copy of your code in my prepared answer. The reason why I didn't post it here, is, that despite the `EnableEvents = False` it seems like the cell value keeps updating itself incorrectly. eg, even with your code, try inputting `4` it changes to `7.37E+19` which is not the correct calculation

Comment: Also one more detail from my solution, it's probably a good idea to do a `isNumeric()` check on Target before firing, to prevent a Type mismatch error

Comment: @Rawrplus  I tried 4 and it came out with 4.27 - using `2010` (just in case).  Definitely agree with the `IsNumeric` though.

Comment: Also, if I could make a suggestion, OP wanted to keep the formula in the background, so maybe `Target.Formula = "=........"` could be a nice addition? :)

Comment: Oops, that was an oversight on my part when it comes to loop. I left a line of code in my older project that fired and re-enabled events. The code works as intended. I posted my version of answer as well as I feel like it provides some further detail (if you don't mind), but I upvoted yours nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how this is better than simply using an extra column with formula, but...

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

  If Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
  'fire only in column A

    If IsNumeric(Target.Value2) Then ' only makes sense to apply if it's a number _
    otherwise it would produce a Type mismatch error

        Application.EnableEvents = False 'to prevent constant looping on change
        Target = Target * 6.75 / 100 + Target
        Application.EnableEvents = True

    Else
         MsgBox ("I can only take numeric values")
    End If

End Sub
```

---

**NOTE:** 
It's important to put the code for `Worksheet_Change` Event inside the module of the respective Sheet Tab.
eg. if you want to the formula to fire in your sheet that is named "`Sheet1"`, you will need to make sure you have the module of `Sheet1` selected:

[image]

Pasting this code anywhere else (eg. `Sheet2`, or `Module 1`) will not work!

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```
Sub YourModuleName()
For Each cell In Application.Selection.Cells
cell.Formula = "=" + CStr(cell.Value) + "*" + "n5"
Next
End Sub
```

n5 is your editable cell

Now, you can highlight a range of cells and run the module to do your calculation